# jquery edit link href if body class = x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to use Jquery and Javascript so that if the body class is x then a link would be y etc 
The code I have is:
http://jsfiddle.net/FzD3B/
HTML

```
<body class="site-name-my-journey-wokingham"> <a id="YTL" href="#">Test</a>

</body>
```

Jquery

```
if ($("body").hasClass(".site-name-my-journey-wokingham")) {
    $("#YTL").attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5qHqdJzjj6QPw3Zsq8dWLQ");
}
```

I've gotten this working before in the past but I can't understand why this currently not working. I've pin pointed that the error is most likely caused by the 2nd line of the Jquery

Comment: `hasClass` doesn't need the preceeding `.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the "hasClass" methods shouldn't contain the "." selector for classes. It already counts just with pure name.

http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

so..

```
if ($("body").hasClass("site-name-my-journey-wokingham"))
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the `.` from [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
if ($("body").hasClass("site-name-my-journey-wokingham")) {
 $("#YTL").attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5qHqdJzjj6QPw3Zsq8dWLQ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove dot from class name.

```
if ($("body").hasClass("site-name-my-journey-wokingham")) {
    $("#YTL").attr("href", "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5qHqdJzjj6QPw3Zsq8dWLQ");
}
```